# Is this a secure method of providing service for database applications?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, security, connection-string

WinFormsApp Login passes information to .php (server based) Login (provided credentials are correct) to DB to retrieve Decryption Key. WinFormsApp then uses Decryption key on Hardcoded encrypted connection string and renders application usable.

This would then eliminate the necessity to encrypt/decrypt a connection string at runtime, virtually rendering any unauthorized person with a useless software.

Is there anything wrong in my thought process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the decryption key is being sent in plain text back to the WinForms application, then that's technically a security hole.  But since you can only get it if you successfully authenticate, it's mitigated somewhat.  To raise the security bar a little higher, you could encrypt the decryption key using a hardcoded encryption key on both ends.  That's not totally fool proof, but sometimes security isn't about being 100% fool proof, it's just raising the bar high enough.  It depends on how secure it needs to be.  A more thoroughly secure design would be to have the server side do all the data access so the client doesn't need the connection string, but that I'm sure would require considerable redesign.  Alternatively, you could use integrated security if it is SQL Server.

Comment: It's a MySQL server. And I don't care if the decryption key is sent in plain text as long as only the people who have access to the software can see it. The target market for my software is fairly tech-illiterate. In that sense, even if someone disassembles my software, they aren't privy to the database and can only see stored procedures.

Comment: Right.  Since it's in plain text, a simple packet sniffer on the network could see it coming across the line, but if you're not worried about them being that savvy, it sounds like a reasonably secure method.